Python Arrays - how to create mask including adjacent grid points within user-specified radius
Am running into a brick wall due to inexperience.  Searches on-line and discussions with fellow python experts here coming up empty.  Have a 2d lat lon grid of wind speed.  Want to create a binary mask showing where wind speed exceeds a specific threshold not just at the local grid point but any grid point within 20km of the given grid point.   Masks just considering the local grid point are simple enough - just trying to find a speedy way to consider the surrounding grid points too without having to go down the road of brute-force iterative looping.
Tested some xarray/numpy methods of rolling and aggregating but too iterative (as I understood how to use them).  Did some online searches and found some close but not quite applicable discussions to our case.
The question is does anyone have recommendations of which array modules and methods to use that have been found to computationally quickly generate such a mask?  We are using grib2 files as sources for our arrays which are quite large since they are at high spatial resolution and extend over large geographical domains.

@spencerclark had a related solution but am not able to duplicate this for our case
